# How can I show only certain file extensions in an open-file dialog?

Tags: delphi, opendialog

When I open a folder with an OpenDialog, how can I filter it so users can view only certain files (e.g., Stringgrid, *.sg) and the files with any other extension do not appear in the dialog window?

Comment: No, you can't do the second (filter files based on something other than extension) if they're in the same folder. But the right solution for that is to give each user their own folder to store files, and use access control (folder rights) to prevent users from seeing each other's files.

Comment: I've removed your second question because it's too different from the original one. Please ask your other question in a separate post.

Answer (score 13):

Set the `OpenDialog.Filter` property to the file filter you want.

You can do this in the Object Inspector:

- Click in the `Filter` property, and you'll see a small button appear on the right edge with `...`.
- Click that, and you'll see a dialog appear.

On the left side is the description of the file (for instance, `Excel files (*.xls)`). The right side is the filter you want to use, as in `*.xls`.

[image: OpenDialog Filter Dialog]

You can also set it in code before displaying your dialog:

```
OpenDialog1.Filter := 'Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls';
```

Of course, replace the Excel stuff with any description and mask you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

The `Filter` and `FilterIndex` properties are used to specify which file extension(s) to display (note that the user can override the filter manually, though).

The `OnIncludeItem` event is used to selectively allow/disallow individual files/folders from being listed in the dialog.